# Background image on wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am trying to get the past images as background using

```
  <div class="sectionrecipes" style="background-image:url('<?php the_field(background_image_detail); ?>');">
```

but it shows blank, i have tried with echo too

```
  <div class="sectionrecipes" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_field(background_image_detail); ?>');">
```

I have checked on developer tool and it shows like this:

```
  <div class="sectionrecipes" style="background-image:url('370, Coole Swan Blue &amp; White Chocolate Custard Pie, blueberry-page, , Coole Swan Blue &amp; White Chocolate Custard Pie, image/jpeg, http://cooleswan.juvoclients.com/wp-content/uploads/blueberry-page.jpg, 1082, 527, Array');">
```

If I delete all the data on the developer tool like this:

```
  <div class="sectionrecipes" style="background-image:url('http://cooleswan.juvoclients.com/wp-content/uploads/blueberry-page.jpg');">
```

The image shows on the page. So How can I stop wordpress to apply the image details?

Than kyou

Answer (score 1):

Your `background_image_detail` is no variable or string and therefore wrong syntax.
It has to be:

```
<?php the_field('background_image_detail'); ?>
```

And you dont have to echo `the_field()` as it already outputs. `get_field()`  will return the value.

Answer (score 1):

In the Custom Feild settings, you'll need to select "Image URL" as the return value. It appears to be currently set to "Image Object"

Comment: Thank you so much... it is perfect now.